# XNA C# Controller Input Structures

Tags: c#, xna, xbox360

I have looked all over the net and need some assistance. Is there a link somewhere to example code of all the buttons for the Xbox 360 controller. For example:

```
if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
    this.Exit();
```

I know this exits the game if you press back on the controller.

I just need examples of states for both joysticks, d-pad, and all the buttons.

Comment: You mean this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.gamepadstate_members.aspx

Comment: @Etienne de Martel Thank you that is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: @Etienne Darn it. I was going to do that, but thought I may as well go ahead and type it up as an answer all fancy like. And it took me way too long, apparently.

Comment: Maybe you can provide more specific text in your question titles. This title doesn't help other users.

Comment: @fire.eagle No worries. There, I'll upvote your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked out the [MSDN XNA input documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197568.aspx)? It doesn't really have examples, but it appears you have the idea of what you do with the inputs.

The articles there have all the information on the inputs.

[All the controller buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.gamepadbuttons_properties.aspx) which you can get to through `GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons`

[The joystick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.gamepadthumbsticks_properties.aspx) which you can get through `GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Thumbsticks`

[And the D-Pad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.gamepaddpad_properties.aspx) which you can get through `GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).DPad`

Answer (score 1):

Also, it's a really good idea to write a wrapper for the buttons.

By this I mean: write a class that checks each button and keeps a state for the button being UP this frame and DOWN last frame, and then it can just report that the button was pushed.

This saves you having to check that every frame and maintain the state in your client code. Derive your class from IGameComponent and add it to your Game class' Component collections at runtime.